# Azure Durable Orchestration - LockAsync

Tags: azure-functions, locking, orchestration

I'm trying to make some locking operations in an Azure durable orchestration.
But I can't figure out how to lock entities.

Lets consider this simple example :

```
public class Function1
{
    [FunctionName(nameof(RunLockOrchestratorHttp))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RunLockOrchestratorHttp(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "RunLockOrchestratorHttp")] HttpRequest req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
    {
        string id = await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(LockOrchestrator), null, "two");
        return new OkObjectResult($"LockOrchestrator started with id {id}");
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(LockOrchestrator))]
    public async Task LockOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var ctx = context.GetInput<string>();

        Console.WriteLine($"LockOrchestrator {context.InstanceId} with context {ctx} : START");

        // Create a locker according to context
        var entity = new EntityId(nameof(LockOrchestrator), ctx);
        using (var locker = await context.LockAsync(entity))
        {
            // Never enter here
            Console.WriteLine($"LockOrchestrator {context.InstanceId} : lock {entity.EntityName}_{entity.EntityKey} obtained");
            await context.CallActivityAsync(nameof(Activity), ctx);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"LockOrchestrator {context.InstanceId} : lock {entity.EntityName}_{entity.EntityKey} released");
    }

    public async Task Activity([ActivityTrigger] string ctx)
    {
        switch (ctx)
        {
            case "one":
                Console.WriteLine($"Activity : wait one");
                await Task.Delay(10000);
                break;
            case "two":
                Console.WriteLine($"Activity : wait two");
                await Task.Delay(20000);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine($"Activity : wait default");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I can see the log

***LockOrchestrator e0c1698674a14b8191faabb7fd3eca69 with context two : START***

But then nothing, I never enter in the using{} statement, where I put the comment ***// Never enter here***

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are trying to lock an entity however, I don't see a definition for that entity. You'll have to define either class based or function based entity first.

For example, if you define an entity class called Counter your code will work.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Counter
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [FunctionName(nameof(Counter))]
    public static Task Run([EntityTrigger] IDurableEntityContext ctx)
        => ctx.DispatchAsync<Counter>();
}
```

Instantiate your entity as:

```
 // Create a locker according to context
    var entity = new EntityId("Counter", ctx);
```

Also, add FunctionName annotation for your activity function to avoid run time error.

```
[FunctionName("Activity")]
public async Task Activity([ActivityTrigger] string ctx)
```

Now this is just an example for entity class. Define entity class based on your needs and try it out.

You may want  to read more on durable entities here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-dotnet-entities

Comment: Ok thanks, it is clearer. But in my architecture, I would like to lock a database area. Is it a good way to use simple objects "Locker" with only the method Run ?

Comment: Would need more details on what exactly you are trying to lock. But one way could be to define Entity Class representing your database table and then any update to that entity should be inside critical section: using (var locker = await context.LockAsync(entity)).  You can also set concurrency/locking properties on database connection.

Comment: Sry for the late. I have a service which will make some calculs on a "red car" for example. And it will compare all the others red cars, that why I need to lock all the red cars before running my service. I don't really have entities to lock. Bu I've made an empty entity for it, it seems to work well